# php mysql Stock market trading game - calculate profit & loss

Tags: mysql

I am writing a stock market trading game base on yahoo using php/mysql & it's almost done. Last part I'm struggling is calculating the profit & loss

Lets say have these as transaction
Starting balance = $5000

```
> order_id stock_id  transaction qty_shares cost  user_id
> 1        1234      B           100        1000  1
> 2        1234      B           50         450   1
> 3        1234      S           80         640   1
> 4        1234      S           30         300   1
```

I'm lost trying to come up with an algorithm or a mysql query to calculate the profit & loss

Added after reading the 2 replies posted below
Additional Note : 
Please take note that in this scenerio 150 shares was purchased & only 110 shares was sold & all was purchased & sold at different prices

Comment: Please take note that in this scenerio 150 shares was purchased & only 110 Shares was sold & all was purchased & sold at different prices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(qty_shares*cost) AS out, user_id, stock_id, order_id
FROM table
WHERE transaction = 'B'
GROUP BY user_id, stock_id, order_id
```

Then:

```
SELECT SUM(qty_shares*cost) AS in, user_id, stock_id
FROM table
WHERE transaction = 'S'
GROUP BY user_id, stock_id, order_id
```

PHP:

```
$Margin = ($query2->in - $query1->out);
$Balance += $Margin;
```

It could all be done on a single query, but if speed is more important then this could be faster than subqueries.

EDIT:
For average profit/loss per share:

```
SELECT AVG(qty_shares/cost) AS price_per_share, transaction, user_id, stock_id
FROM table
GROUP BY transaction,user_id,stock_id
```

This should return the average price per share for each transaction type, per stock type per user. so the transaction S row is average price sold for, and transaction B row is average price bought for. The difference between them is average profit or loss.

```
SELECT 
SUM(
qty_shares *
    (
      SELECT AVG(A.qty_shares/A.cost) AS price_per_share
      FROM table AS A
      WHERE A.transaction = table.transaction
      AND   A.user_id = table.user_id
      AND   A.stock_id = table.stock_id
    )
), user_id, stock_id, order_id
FROM table
WHERE transaction = 'B'
GROUP BY user_id, stock_id, order_id
```

That query should return the number of shares sold per row multiplied by the current average price per share, giving you the average margin per transaction with the sold margin being negative. You may find the query slow though. I'd recommend using this information as a starting point and finding the best way for your application.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I came out with the similar queries your but as you notice there are 150 shares purchased & only 110 shares sold. as the price of the shares was purchases at different prices I'm stuck as what algorithm or s mysql query to use. Do I consider FIFO or average & how can I do it using query

Comment: If your concerned with the cost per shares, which you seem to be indicating in your comment the forumlae is numberOfShares / cost. If the exact cost per share is no too important you can average the cost to acheieve the average profit per share.

Comment: Yes that was my concern, do I need to have a seperate table for that ?

Comment: See the edit for more detail on cost per share. you can retrieve it by query and store it in a PHP variable then multiply it by the number of shares sold each row OR do it in the query with a sub query. I'd reccomend PHP personally it'll probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Well you would simply loop over each row and calculate the balance.

Obviously this code will be completely dependant on your existing code and how you've got the rows out of the database(?), but if you're looking to just get an overall figure you could do something like this (based on `cost` being share):

```
$start_balance = 5000;
$balance = $start_balance;
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    switch($transaction->transaction) {
        case 'B':
            $balance -= $transaction->qty_shares * $transaction->cost;
            break;
        case 'S':
            $balance += $transaction->qty_shares * $transaction->cost;
            break;
   }
}

$profitloss = $balance - $startbalance;
```

If `$profitloss` is negative, they made a loss based on the transactions within `$transactions`.

Of course you could also extend this to show a profit/loss balance based on each transaction that is performed. Something like this:

```
$start_balance = 5000;
$balance = $start_balance;
foreach ($transactions as $transaction) {
    $start_balance = $balance;
    switch($transaction->transaction) {
        case 'B':
            $balance -= $transaction->qty_shares * $transaction->cost;
            break;
        case 'S':
            $balance += $transaction->qty_shares * $transaction->cost;
            break;
   }
   $transaction->profitloss = $balance - $startbalance;
}
```

That way, each individual transaction would have a profit/loss related to it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond but I'm more incline to look into mysql query in this case. As you may notice there are 150 shares purchase but only 110 sold & there are still 40 left unsold. how do you addres that ?

Comment: It would end up producing a fairly complex query to calculate this and honestly I'd see little benefit to doing this in MySQL. Are you wanting to get it per transaction, or globally? If globally, when you insert the transaction, calculate a new balance, if per transaction, calculate it upon insertion (a 'total' column). You can them sum them all up when you need to get the data out.

Comment: I M looking at the best way to do it. A simplest way possible,

Comment: Both solutions (both MySQL and PHP) are a *very* simple way to achieve what you desire.

Comment: All my transaction are stored in mysql do I loop it to qty the quantity bought sold value ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.. The calculation you are doing is simple addition/subtraction of a multiplication of two values on a row. You also need the base number (balance) that you are adding to/subtracting from.

Comment: Your suggestion of new balance is very interesting. Can you eloborate more on this ?

Comment: Well I mean you would keep a running balance for each user that is playing your game, and keep a transaction log based on profit/loss to calculate this new balance. The alternative I suggested involved a balance offset ie. total profit/loss per transaction. Both would work just fine..

Comment: Yes that would be very simple but the issue is qty shares unsold & the amount unsold I need to considered. How can I take that into equation ?

Comment: You don't need to care about that, the balance would be first offset by -1000 when they buy shares, and then if they only sold 80%, it would go back up +800. This results in an overall loss of 200, which is correct.